# Exclude manylinux wheels when downloading from pip

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

At $company we run an internal pypi server to shield ourselves from public pypi downtime.  We also build wheels to avoid installation overhead for binary packages.  One common task is to import packages from public pypi which essentially boils down to:

```
pip install --download . --no-binary :all: $PACKAGE  # download a source distribution
```

and

```
pip wheel $PACKAGE  # build a binary distribution (or use a cached version that's already on our internal pypi)
```

Under the latest pip, this may download / install `manylinux` wheels during the `pip wheel` phase.  Due to bundling .so files *inside* the wheel, these are incompatible with our security requirements at $company.  How can we continue the same workflow while avoiding the manylinux wheels?

Currently we're downgrading to `pip<8`, but this seems non-ideal

Comment: I've opened a bug with pip project for similar issue. https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3689

As far as I know, there is no way to disable downloading of manylinux wheels at this moment.

Answer (score 3):

#### Workaround

As a workaround you can create file `_manylinux.py` in current workdir, or in the `site-packages` with following content:

```
manylinux1_compatible = False
```

This will ensure that manylinux1 wheels won't be downloaded when you run your commands:

```
pip wheel -w path/to/wheeldir -f path/to/wheeldir -r requirements.txt
```

You don't really need to use two commands `pip install --download` and `pip wheel`, but you can use single command above. (please note, that `pip install --download` is deprecated in favor of `pip download` command).

Command as I suggested will:

1. Check if wheel already exists in `path/to/wheeldir` and will not touch that wheel.
2. If new version was detected in requirements file (or you can replace `-r requirements.txt` with package and exact version `package==X.X.X`) and wheel is universal -- it will download that wheel and store it into `path/to/wheeldir`.
3. If package requires compiling (example `numpy`, or `matplotlib`) -- source tgz will be downloaded and pip will build the wheel, and resulting wheel will be stored in the `path/to/wheeldir`.

I've tested this solution, which was [suggested in the [pypa/pip#3689](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3689#issuecomment-219437150). It is **not the solution** we need, but it is workable and I use it.

#### Where can you put `_manylinux.py` file?

PIP [attempts to import _manylinux module](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/8.1.2/pip/pep425tags.py#L149).

Q: Where Python will look for it?
A: Python follows [the module search path](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).

So you can put your file in following locations:

1. current work dir.
2. Path in your `PYTHONPATH`.
3. Installation default path.

First two paths are simple, but how you find your installation default path? Simply run following command:

```
python -c "import os.path as p;print(p.dirname(p.realpath(p.__file__)))"
```

Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 3):

For those looking for an installable workaround, I've created [no-manylinux](https://github.com/asottile/no-manylinux)

The usage is relatively straightforward:

```
# First install no-manylinux
pip install no-manylinux
# Now subsequent invocations of pip will ignore manylinux wheels
pip install ...
# To restore the original behaviour, simply `pip uninstall no-manylinux`
```

It works by installing a `_manylinux.py` file with `manylinux_compatible = False` as the contents

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to use only source distributions and not wheels when using wheels. To do this add this `--no-use-wheel` to your pip command.

This sounds a bit counter intuitive to use this when building a wheel, but it really means `Do not Find and prefer wheel archives when searching indexes and find-links locations.` This should force the fetching of remote source dists instead of wheels during the wheel phase for any of the deps you depend on.

Comment: `--no-use-wheel` will exclude py2.py3-none-any wheels as well as "correctly" compiled linux_x86_64 wheels (on an internal pypi) so it is a non-solution.

Comment: For the same reason `--no-binary :all:` (pip>=8 option) is also not sufficient

Comment: So you are stuck in corner. You need to vendor in your repo ahead of time all the dependencies you need at full depth as pre-built wheel. And never depend on the main Pypi.

Comment: Note that in the possible case where things could still work out, you could run pip in verbose mode to get a lot of the details that are going on.